# Passing a string from PHP to Perl and get back a return string

Tags: php, perl

I want to pass a string from within a PHP script to a Perl script. The Perl script will do some regex processing with the string, and finally return another string, which should be captured by the PHP script. How can I accomplish this? Is there any contingency like installing some new module, or installing Perl in WAMP as well (currently perl is installed in **C:\**, and I am working in WAMP)?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself but I think you should be able to call the perl script using the `exec()` command or the likes from PHP, pass the data to it and read the output back.

Edit:

```
$output = exec("c:\\whatever\\directory\\script.pl data");
```

I am not entirely sure on how the parameters are passed to perl script through the command line, so you might have to experiment on the command line a bit to figure that out.

Or if the perl script is being used through the URL you can use

`$output = file_get_contents("http://whatever/url?data=whateverdata")`